# Windows x86 assembly entry point is wrong

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, portable-executable, entry-point

I wrote a test program for learning purposes in x86 assembly using **NASM** as assembler and **MinGW32** (ld) as linkerW.
I am working on Windows 10.

```
section .text

global my_start
my_start:

nop
nop
nop
nop

jmp my_start
```

I am using the following command for assembling:

> nasm -f win32 -l main.lst main.asm

And the following command for linking:

> ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -s -o main.exe -e my_start main.obj

Now if I run the program I get an sgmentation fault error.
To find out why I used **GDB** for debugging and found out that windows is executing my executable at file begin where the **DOS Header** is laying.
So windows is trying to execute the magic number "MZ" (4d 5a) and following bytes as assembler instructions.

So, now I am very confused why this happens because I specified an entry point (**-e my_start**) followed by valid x86 assembler instructions.

Why exactly my executable start's execute at DOS header and not at my specified entry point in my code segment?
How I can fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried now GoLink and using this linker everything is working fine:

> GoLink.exe main.obj /entry my_start

I also compared the entry point of the optional header and both are equal.
But comparing both files a lot of things are different so I cannot tell what exactly is wrong so I will stick with GoLink for a while and maybe come back to this problem if I have a bit more experience.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but Windows does sometimes get confused by very small executables.  Just in case, it might be worth trying padding the contents out so that the executable is at least 4096 bytes long.

Comment: need looking in some PE viewer - are `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint` is 0 ?

Comment: also if you nothing import and nothing doing in code (senseless jump compiler/linker can optimize - just throw) - you really have no code at all - so linker can set `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint` to 0 but still create formal "valid" exe which of course begin execute from `MZ` as 0 entry point - so and crash

Comment: I'd be very surprised if either NASM or ld were detecting infinite loops, but I suppose it might be a "magic sequence" so to speak, i.e., *perhaps* GCC generates that assembly code as a signal to the linker to do something odd.  Do you get the same result if the code is anything else?

Comment: As an option, you could try Visual Studio C/C++ Express 2015 (it's free), which includes ML.EXE (32 bit MASM) and ML64.EXE (64 bit MASM). It includes an ide, assembler, compiler, linker, and source level debugger. Create an "empty" project, then add source file(s).  I use a custom build step on the assembly source in a project:  ml /c /Zi  /Fo$(OutDir)\example.obj example.asm for the build step, $(OutDir)\example.obj for output file. That's for debug build, for release build don't use /Zi.